# php smarty-like inheritance in twig template engine

Tags: php, inheritance, twig, smarty

The only php template engine which can handle inheritance to support e.g. a plugin-system is smarty - because it supports to load a parent template and also one or more child templates at the same time.

I couldn't find this in twig, dwoo, lette or similar template engines.

To be exact, I mean this:
https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.extends.tpl

```
+- index.tpl // the parent template
|
+--- child.tpl // a child which extends the parent
+--- child2.tpl // another child which extends the parent
```

Smarty will load this like so:

```
$smarty->display('index.tpl|child.tpl|child2.tpl');
```

Since I use the twig template engine in personal projects and it doesn't seems to support this feature I would appreciate any suggestions.

Sorry if I am wrong here but I don't know another place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Twig can extend parent templates quite easily.

```
{% extends "parent.twig" %}
```

Check out the docs:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html

Comment: Yes, but this only supports that one child extend the parent at the same time. I need at least two child templates which extends the parent.